# curiosity about magical &x in PHP & Drupal7

Tags: php, get, drupal-7

During my work, I found a strange result. I missed my "ALT+TAB" to switch my screen and wrote "&x" instead in the end of my php line, which looks like :

```
<?='<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b>'&x;?>
```

What I'm coding is a search engine for a jobs site. The code above returns the number of result from the form and not the title. So, in my search page, I've got for example :

```
<?='<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b>'&x;?> files has been found for <?='<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b>';?> job.
```

(8 files has been found for Developer job)

In fact,

```
<?='<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b>'&x;?> **returns 8 results (which is good)**
<?='<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b>';?> **returns Developer**
```

What is this case with "&x" ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case PHP is trying  to get reference from undefined constant x. 
In a case of not define constant PHP assume that it's a String and returns reference to the string object that it's created automatically.
This will work only if you have a string before the &x expression. Personally i think that this is a bug.
Try to run this code

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );
$_GET['title'] = "title";
?>
<?= 'sds'&x;?>
<?='<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b>'&x;?>
<?php 
exit();
```

Comment: "sds = p" and "<b>'.$_GET['title'].'</b> = 8".
What kind of relation is that ? I'm sure it's useless to know that but it's intriguing. Let's go to create a new MD5 :p
What are your thoughts about this "bug" ?

Comment: "sds = p" the char p is a 70  in a hex, I think is a first char of address of the newly created String object